# Find function from given power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Given the power series, using differentiation and integration, find the function represented by the power series:
$$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}$$

By integrating this I get $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$ and I know that this is the function $f(x)=\frac1{1-x}$, but I am unaware if I am missing any steps or simply stating the function right after integrating is correct?

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need differentiation or integration. $S(x)$ is well defined in the unit ball and:
$$ (1-x)\cdot S(x) = (1-x)\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} n x^{n-1} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\left(n x^{n-1}-n x^{n}\right)=\sum_{n\geq 1}x^{n-1} = \frac{1}{1-x}$$
from which:
$$ S(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2} $$
follows. As an alternative:
$$ S(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n\geq 1}x^n = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-1\right)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.$$

Comment: Yes, I understand, however, it is a coursework question that specifically says that it must be solved using differentiation or integration.

Comment: @AndrejNaumovski: answer updated.

Comment: Thank you. Now, if I were to have $$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^n$$, what would be the steps to solving it?

Comment: @AndrejNaumovski: just multiply by $x$ the $S(x)$ in my answer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you meant, sorry. Could you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: @AndrejNaumovski: $$\sum_{n\geq 1}n x^n = x\cdot\sum_{n\geq 1}n x^{n-1} = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}.$$